# In Delphi, how can I make a button appear on top of a TCheckListBox?

Tags: delphi, button, tchecklistbox

We want a list box with check boxes and formatted text. We get that using a `TCheckListBox` in owner-draw mode.

But we would like to also have a button appear at the right end of the selected row. Just adding a button (`TSpeedButton`) with the CheckListBox as the Parent doesn't get drawn correctly.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Draw the button as well. Handle the input events in the control to respond to it being pressed.

Comment: You should include an MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your q to show what you are doing.